# Problems with booting with Kubuntu 13.04 / Windows 7 Dual boot

Tags: boot, windows, dual-boot, boot-loader, kubuntu

So I've had Kubuntu running on my Lenovo laptop as the only operating system for most of the summer. Earlier this week, I decided to shrink the home partition in order to add a Windows 7 partition.

After installing Windows 7, I was then stuck where I could boot into Windows 7, but could not boot into Kubuntu. I ended up using a Kubuntu live USB in order to use the boot-repair tool, which let me regain access to GRUB, which now correctly lists Kubuntu and Windows 7 as the bootable operating systems, but it crashes any time I try to boot into windows. It is able to successfully boot into Kubuntu.

I ran the windows startup repair tool several times without success, as well as re-running the boot repair tool. Below is a link to the boot repair summary from the most recent attempt at boot-repair.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6146103/

Any suggestions as to how I could fix this without just wiping the drives and starting over?

Comment: Is GRUB showing both windows and kubuntu at boot time or is not displaying anything at all?

Comment: It shows both as options. If I select kubuntu, it boots successfully. If I select windows, it makes it to [this](http://howtoformatacomputer.com/wp-content/uploads/Install-Windows-7-3-Starting-Windows.jpg) screen before crashing and immediately restarting.

Comment: Also, although the pasted summary says that the problem has been repaired, the problem has persisted.

Comment: Look at lines 88 and 91, you've got two filesystems at the same partition, I think that at some point one of those tools did not sync the partition table and the info at GRUB, did you repair the partiotion to the point before the shrink?.

Comment: You mean repair back to the point before I made the new partition for windows 7? No, I haven't. Also, line 88 appears to be blank to me, so I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: I think you or the repair tool wrote to / and it touched some files in the windows partition wich is the same `sda2` and that caused the error.